# can't save strlen return value

Tags: c, string-length

I am using c string library's strlen function.I passed a NULL
string to it and found mysterious result.I know I am not supposed to pass NULL string but I need an explanation for it.The code looks something like this

```
main()
{
  int k;
  char *s=NULL;
  strlen(s);
  // k = strlen(s);
}
```

On my gcc compiler ,It runs fine with the comment.
but if you will remove the comment in the line
`k=strlen(s);`

it produces segmentation fault.
Any explanation ?

Comment: Just a wild guess, `strlen(s)` might be optimized out, since this function has no side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the assembler code without assignment to the int variable

```
movq    $0, -16(%rbp)
movl    $0, %eax
leave
ret
```

the compiler don't call _strlen because the value will not used

Answer (score 3):

Passing a null pointer to `strlen` results in *undefined behvaiour*.  **Anything could happen.**  Including seg-faults.  And including no seg-faults.

If you want to know the exact reason, then you will need to look at the assembler code that your compiler generates.  But this will not tell you anything useful.

Comment: "Anything could happen. Including seg-faults." - and, less intuitively, including no seg-faults.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking why a segmentation fault happens for the `k=strlen(s);` call, but why it does *not* happen for the first `strlen(s);` call.

Answer (score 3):

The first 'strlen' call that is not assigning its return value is probably being optimized out by your compiler.

Comment: True.  But `k` is not being used either, so by the same argument, the compiler would be free to optimise the entire thing away.

Comment: @Oli: I think it may depend on optimization level. Perhaps the level set will execute the assignment statement inside comments.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler simply isn't _that_ smart.  You could try compiling to assembly and looking at the result to see exactly what is being done with your code.

Comment: Simple enough to turn off optimization and see if the behavior changes.